# PowerShell Get-ADUser, output to JSON with formatted DateTime

Tags: json, powershell, formatting, get-aduser

I'll say first that I'm not very experienced with PowerShell, so many things are not obvious to me.

I've got the following command:

```
$JSON = Get-ADUser -Filter "SAMAccountName -eq 'jdray'" -Properties SAMAccountName,
    Name,
    DisplayName,
    Manager,
    SAMAccountType,
    pwdLastSet,
    Created,
    AccountExpirationDate,
    lastLogonTimestamp,
    DistinguishedName|Select-object -Property SAMAccountName,
                                    Name,
                                    @{name='Manager';expression={ ([ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.manager)").displayname }},
                                    Enabled,
                                    DistinguishedName,
                                    Created,
                                    AccountExpirationDate,
                                    LastLogonTimestamp,
                                    PasswordLastSet|ConvertTo-Json
```

The output of this is:

```
{
    "SAMAccountName":  "jdray",
    "Name":  "Ray, James",
    "Manager":  "Lady, Boss",
    "Enabled":  true,
    "DistinguishedName":  "CN=Ray\\, James,OU=...[yadda yadda yadda]...DC=com",
    "Created":  "\/Date(1554387070000)\/",
    "AccountExpirationDate":  "\/Date(1643702400000)\/",
    "LastLogonTimestamp":  132732539928955494,
    "pwdLastSet":  132729945927805005
}
```

First of all, I'm confused why `AccountExpirationDate` and `Created` have one format, but `LastLogonTimestamp` and `pwdLastSet` are formatted differently.

What I really want is to have all the `DateTime` objects output in a human-readable `DateTime` format.  I tried `-ExpandProperty`, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.  It appears to add a property named `DateTime` to the end of the output, formatted reasonably: `"DateTime":  "Thursday, April 4, 2019 7:11:10 AM"`, but it doesn't name it.  The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#examples) on the subject is very light on useful examples, as is the rest of the web.

I tried following the `@{}` format for the **Manager** expression, which I copied from someone else's script.  Unfortunately my PowerShell isn't strong enough to figure out a reasonable expression.  In C#, something like `Created.ToShortDateString()` would suffice (presuming `Created` is a `DateTime`).

So, how do I consistently output named, human-readable `DateTime` property values in a JSON array?

**EDIT**

Using a proposed answer below, I modified the four timestamp fields using the same pattern:

```
@{n='Created';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.Created)}},
@{n='AccountExpirationDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpirationDate)}},
@{n='LastLogonTimestamp';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}},
@{n='pwdLastSet';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)}}
```

Here's the (frustrating) result I got:

```
 "Created":  "\/Date(1554387070000)\/",
 "AccountExpirationDate":  "\/Date(1643702400000)\/",
 "LastLogon":  {
                   "value":  "\/Date(1628780392895)\/",
                   "DateTime":  "Thursday, August 12, 2021 7:59:52 AM"
               },
 "pwdLastSet":  132729945927805005
```

Also of note, here's the output for the four `DateTime` fields before it gets translated to JSON:

```
Created               : 4/4/2019 7:11:10 AM
AccountExpirationDate : 2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM
LastLogonTimestamp    : 8/12/2021 7:59:52 AM
PasswordLastSet       : 8/9/2021 7:56:32 AM
```

Why does that formatting work for one `DateTime` instance but not the rest?

How do I extract `DateTime` from the format of the `pwdLastSet` field, which is clearly a different animal?

How do I get a simple `property:value` pair, such as `"LastLogonTimestamp":  "Thursday, August 12, 2021 7:59:52 AM"`?

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.FromFileTime(LastLogonTimestamp)
$JSON=Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogon |
Select-Object Name,Manager,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}

Comment: Where?  In the expression, such as `@{Name='LastLogonTimestamp';expression=DateTime.FromFileTime(LastLogonTimestamp)}`??

Comment: Tried that (in my previous comment) and it didn't work.

Comment: $JSON= Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Name,Manager,LastLogon | 
Select-Object Name,Manager,@{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}

Comment: That looks promising, but please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Promising indeed.  Modified for the correct fieldname, it returns `"LastLogonTimestamp":  {
                                           "value":  "\/Date(1629122614234)\/",
                                           "DateTime":  "Monday, August 16, 2021 7:03:34 AM"
                                       }`.  How do I get it to return ` "LastLogonTimestamp":  "Monday, August 16, 2021 7:03:34 AM" '?